# Convert pdf to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, conversion, file-conversion

I have a pdf of 18,000 pages of data that I need to work with for a project. I'm trying to convert it to an excel spreadsheet.

I can't use Acrobat because it's just for a summer project thus I don't want to buy it.

Is there any other way that I could possibly do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to include what have you tried and what version of Excel are you using. This will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that PDFs are a programming language unto themselves. I can draw first at the bottom of the page (or screen), then at the top, then overlay something.

That said, we use [pdftotext](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) for this very task, with some massaging of the output after.

You might also be able to load it in either Google Docs, or even LibreOffice has PDF converters.

All 3 of these are free, try which helps the most.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nuance PDF Converter Pro.  It converts PDF files into many different formats and it's not designed to empty your bank account as Adobe likes to do.

[This link takes you to Nuance's home page on PDF Converter and give you a free trial!](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/document-imaging-and-scanning/power-pdf-converter-standard/index.htm)